# Unity c# mario game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following this youtube series that creates a Unity 3D Mario game.
( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjL3S5dKLN4&index=6&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKgm4QrzZ11jfaeHVaWHSHW7 )

So I am trying to recreate the "going down the pipe" script like on the Mario game. I create an **Animator** and I am trying to trigger the animation using a C# script on key down press.

**1. The problem:**
This guys writes his scripts in Javascript and apparently my Unity version does no longer support js so I need to write it in C# ( and I prefer writing it in C#).

Basically I need to convert this js to c#:

```
var PipeEntry : GameObject;
var StoodOn : int;


function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
    StoodOn = 1;
}

function OnTriggerExit (col : Collider) {
    StoodOn = 0;
}


function Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("GoDown")) {
        if (StoodOn == 1) {
            //GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent("FirstPersonController").enabled=false;
            transform.position = Vector3(0, -1000, 0);
            WaitingForPipe();
        }
    }
}

function WaitingForPipe () {
    PipeEntry.GetComponent("Animator").enabled=true;
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    PipeEntry.GetComponent("Animator").enabled=false;
    //GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent("FirstPersonController").enabled=true;
}
```

**2. MY CODE**

My script currently looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// 
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class PipeEntry : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pipe_entry;
    public int StoodOn;
    public int has_run = 0;
    public int waiting_pipe = 0;
    public int waiting_pipe_animation = 0;

    IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        StoodOn = 1;
        yield return StoodOn;
    }

    IEnumerator OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        StoodOn = 0;
        yield return StoodOn;
    }

    IEnumerator WaitPipeAnimation()
    {
        waiting_pipe_animation = 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("PipeDown"))
        {
            if (StoodOn == 1)
            {
                // Freeze player
                //GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;
                transform.position = new Vector3(0, -1000, 0);
                WaitingForPipe();
                has_run = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void WaitingForPipe()
    {
        pipe_entry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
        WaitPipeAnimation();
        pipe_entry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        waiting_pipe = 1;
        //GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
}
```

**3. Facts**

- The animation works good if triggered directly from Unity, so the script does not work.
- I set some debug variables that are set to value 1 too where script breaks and **waiting_pipe_animation** is the only one that doesn't reach.

**4. UPDATE**
- So basically the main issue is with this function:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
```

If I place it in a **void function** I get this:

> The body cannot be a iterator block because void is not a iterator
>   interface type.

If I set animation to **true** and never set it back to **false**, it works - but not as expected because obviously animation goes forever.

Comment: You start coroutines using `StartCoroutine`: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The functions [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [`OnTriggerExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html) don't return IEnumerator and aren't coroutines.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    StoodOn = 1;
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    StoodOn = 0;
}
```

**2.** If the character is going to have more than one animation, I suggest you to create transitions between the animations and create variables to control it. There are some useful functions, like [SetFloat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html), [SetInteger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetInteger.html), [SetBool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html), [SetTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html) and so on. If not, enabling and disabling the animator like you did will be fine.

**3.** As stated by Okeme Christian, it's required to use `StartCoroutine("WaitPipeAnimation")` to call your coroutine.

**4.** `pipe_entry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;` should be inside the WaitPipeAnimation function, because all the code ouside it will still be executed in the same frame. So basically you are activating and deactivating the animator in the same frame and won't be able to see the animation.

```
IEnumerator WaitPipeAnimation()
{
    waiting_pipe_animation = 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    pipe_entry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
}
```

If you want to understand better how it works, please test this code below:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("CoroutineTest");
    Debug.Log("3");
}

IEnumerator CoroutineTest()
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    Debug.Log("2");
}
```

Note that the print order in the console will be "1", "3", "2".

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! Today Im away but I will try this tomorrow and resolve if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You cant call a coroutine as a function. Instead you start a coroutine like this

```
   StartCoroutine("Fade");
```

Where Fade is the coroutine name, so in your case you will start it like this

```
   StartCoroutine("WaitPipeAnimation")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, see the updated ( i edited the question ) so I identified the problem but I don't know how to fix it. About the tutorial being old - I am quite new to this, and the game I have in mind is very similar to Mario so I tought this tutorial would be perfect to get started.